# OpenSuse TW - wake up from sleep issue

Tags: opensuse, sleep

I have ThinkPad L13 yoga gen 2 running OpenSUSE TW with KDE/Wayland and after going to sleep it won't wake up and throws the following
[image: error]

Tried to sleep laptop using X11 this is what I get:
[image]

Also note that after hard reboot everything is fine and I can use my laptop as usual.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Does that happen on `Xorg`? It looks like you have problems with your nvme (or the filesystem, I'm not sure of that)

Comment: X11 is a bit different see my edit.

Comment: It looks like your nvme has problems or maybe the filesystem btrfs is corrupted. When you boot up, try logging (actually you have the prompt for login) or if that did not work then try using another virtual console. Press for example `Ctrl+Alt+F2` and you will get the prompt for your user name: `localhost login: `, after typing your user you will get the prompt for the password: `Password`